# Flutter create vertical calendar

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

I am trying to create a list of months, and their days [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtLDr.gif), using a vertical pageview wont do, because the months don't all have the same size, and a listview does not let me set a default position easily. Is there a good way to approach this that I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found https://pub.dev/packages/indexed_list_view which lets me do exactly what I want to, scroll in any direction, and jump to a location :)

Comment: what do you think about performance issues? if a calendar has many years and many months, for example, when a day should be customized by a click, all days have to be recalculated each time. how did you solve this?